# CSS inline-block li elements not aligning horizontally

Tags: css

Building css horizontal menu where I apply the padding and inline-block elements to the link itself so the entire block can be clicked instead of just the link text. Normally I float my UL nest menu, but event if I float this list it still stacks vertically, which I suspect is due to the inline-block. I would prefer not to use float since the few examples I have seen show that this can be done, but I have had no luck getting the inline-block or flat to work with my css.

EXAMPLE: 
http://jsfiddle.net/n4fkb66L/

HTML

```
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Link 1 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Link 2 </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Link 3 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F9F5EA;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 6.25em;
}

#navigation {
  height: 6.25em;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #333;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #333;
          box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #333;
}

#navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#naviation ul li {
}

#navigation ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 6.25em;
  width: 10em;
  line-height: 6.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #DE5842;
}

#navigation ul li a:active {
  background-color: #6CBDF2;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding `display:inline-block` on the `<li>`?

```
#navigation li{
     display: inline-block;   
}
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4fkb66L/3/).

Explanation: Even f your  elements are with `display:inline-block`, the `<li>` still occupied the entire line, thus not leaving space for the next `<li>` element and forcing it to go to the next line.

Comment: Yes it is a good solution. Just mind the extra bracket in the end of the css-fiddle. It should be deleted :-)

Comment: @Cfrim thanks for the tip, I always forget that jsfiddle adds that bracket automatically, and go ahead and add one myself... xD

Comment: +1) I didn't notice that OP is using wrong spelling of navigation `#naviation ul li {...}` instead of `#navigation ul li {...}` in CSS :)

Comment: @Hristo No problem :) I know what you are talking about.

Comment: OMG.. TY, I did not realize I misspelled the navigation for the UL LI element. Works now, so happy.